# Why the forEach() method is not working in promise object arrow function ES6?

Tags: javascript, foreach, arrow-functions

I've learnt Javascript for 2 weeks, now i'm learning promise in Javascript, doing some examples in course and i'm having a bit of a problem here. The forEach() method in there **is working**

```
    data.comments.forEach(function (comment) {
      var user = data.users.find((user) => user.id === comment.userId);
      html += `<li>${user.name}: ${comment.content}</li>`;
    });
```

But the forEach() method below **is not working**

```
    data.comments.forEach((comment) => {
      var user = data.users.find((user) => {
        return user.id === comment.userId;
      });
      html += `<li>${user.name}: ${comment.content}</li>`;
    });
```

And this is my source code

```
var users = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "User 1",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "User 2",
  },
];

var comments = [
  {
    id: 1,
    userId: 1,
    content: "Content written by User id 1",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    userId: 2,
    content: "Content written by User id 2",
  },
];
function getUserByIds(userIds) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    var results = users.filter((user) => userIds.includes(user.id));
    setTimeout(() => resolve(results), 2000);
  });
}
function getComments() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(comments), 2000);
  });
}

getComments()
  .then((comments) => {
    var userIds = comments.map((comment) => {
      return comment.userId;
    });
    return userIds;
  })
  .then((userIds) => {
    return getUserByIds(userIds);
  })
  .then((users) => {
    return {
      users: users,
      comments: comments,
    };
  })
  .then((data) => {
    var commentBlock = document.querySelector("#comment-block");
    var html = "";
    // data.comments.forEach((comment) => {
    //   var user = data.users.find((user) => {
    //     return user.id === comment.userId;
    //   });
    //   html += `<li>${user.name}: ${comment.content}</li>`;
    // });
    data.comments.forEach(function (comment) {
      var user = data.users.find((user) => user.id === comment.userId);
      html += `<li>${user.name}: ${comment.content}</li>`;
    });
    commentBlock.innerHTML = html;
  });
```

Why is this not working with ES6 arrow functions? 
Thanks all,

Comment: Check if the browser version you are using support ES6 arrow functions

Comment: It is actually working in my environment, try to check your environment ES6 support

Comment: I have a feeling that this is related to the scope of arrow functions.

Comment: Can you elaborate what "not working" means?

Comment: After reading it again, I think it is not a problem of ES6 support because you are actually using arrow functions inside the `find` method. As told, elaborate better what it is not working

Comment: @lissettdm Seriously, what modern browser does not support arrow functions?

Comment: Your code works just fine for me, the produced `html` is `"<li>User 1: Content written by User id 1</li><li>User 2: Content written by User id 2</li>"`.

Comment: When i checked it again, i realized that variable `comment.userIds` has an extra letter **s**